# How to get particular row and column value on click of table

Tags: jquery-ui

I am created a dynamic table, now I want value of particular row and column on which I had click how to get that. Following is my code

```
var theader = '<table border="1">\n';
        var tbody = '';

        for (var out = 1;out<substr.length-1;out++)
        {
            //alert(substr[out]);

            tbody += '<tr>';

            var pra = substr[out].split('|^');
            //alert('pra.length is: '+pra.length);
            for (var i=0;i<pra.length-1;i++)
            {
                tbody += '<td>';
                tbody += pra[i];                    
                tbody += '</td>' 

            }
            tbody += '</tr>\n';

        }

        //createTable();
        var tfooter = '</table>';
        document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
```

Comment: Hi, in this case, assign the CSS class to the <tr> and <td> and write a jquery function on click of tr and td, you will get the current element and you can process the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign an id to table

```
var theader = '<table border="1" id=\"tableId\">\n';
```

and then Write jquery like this

**Demo**
    http://jsfiddle.net/75zFX/4/

```
$(function(){
    $("#tableIdtr td").on("click",function() {
       alert($(this).html());
       //OR $(this).text()

    });
});​
```

Comment: Hi Felix and CoDe thanks for reply. CoDe  I tried with your suggestion but still not getting alert

Comment: Hi CoDe thank you very much  for valuable response and Demo. But still I am not getting click.

Comment: are you able to run the demo successfully

Comment: Yes I can run Demo successfully

Comment: Because of some technical problem of this site I am not able to post whole code.But below are first lines of my function:

Comment: I am not able to post here will you give me your mail id?

Comment: Oh thanks now it works like charm. Thank you very much for your valuable time and response